# Convert .smp downloaded from NCBI CDD into HMM(.hmm) file

Tags: proteins, phylogenetics, hmmer, domains

Is there a method or tool to convert a .smp file from CDD (Protein Domain File) into a HMM file? I downloaded the CDD files from the FTP site and am more familiar with domain searching with the HMMer suite.